# interesting issue with chaining array methods and push

Tags: javascript, push

Was messing around with some array stuff earlier and discovered a very peculiar caveat

consider this code:

`[1,2,3].map(function(el) { return el * 2}).push(4*2).join(" ");`

In writing it, I expected to get: `2, 4, 6, 8`

instead, it threw an exception. in investigating further, the `.push` returns the adjusted `.length` of the passed array:

```
[1,2,3].map(function(el) { return el * 2}).push(4*2);
>>> 4

[1,2,3,4].map(function(el) { return el * 2}).push("hi");
>>> 5
```

and typeof is number, so the `.join` throws as it's not in the number proto.

it seems you can pass on / chain any other array methods but not push. though this is not a problem and it works if you pass on the result into a variable, why is breaking as is and why is the length property being returned here?

this works fine...

```
var foo = [1,2,3,4].map(function(el) { return el * 2});
foo.push(5*2);
console.log(foo); 
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

probably another wtfjs moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the length property being returned here?

It is defined in the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.7):

> The arguments are appended to the end of the array, in the order in which they appear. The new length of the array is returned as the result of the call.

> Why is breaking as is?

Well, you answered this already yourself: `.push` returns the new length and `.join` is not defined for numbers.

Comment: ah so this is intended behavior? thanks for that, may I ask why is it considered useful to return the length and not the array, which will contain the length property for inspection if so desired? seems like an odd architectural decision.

Comment: Well, I cannot tell you *why* they decided to do this, I could only make assumptions. One reason could have been that there is not reason to return a reference to the array, as `.push` changes the array *in-place*.